# XPath select dates after timezone conversion

Tags: php, date, xpath

With the following xml

```
<SomeData>
<MyData uID="123456">
<MyInfo A="1" B="2" C="3">
<Date>2011-10-02 00:30:00</Date>
</MyData>
<MyData uID="123456">
<MyInfo A="1" B="2" C="3">
<Date>2011-10-01 00:30:00</Date>
</MyData>
<SomeData>
```

I need to be able to select based on the date part of Date. First though as these dates are set as GMT I would need to alter the Date to the correct time zone and then select the dates I need.

i.e if I was looking for dates on the 2011-10-01 but for GMT-5 I would need the xpath to select the first date and not the second.

I am using php and my code is currently like this, but this does not alter the date yet.

```
$results = $this->myxml->xpath("//SomeData[MyData/Date[starts-with(.,'".$searchDate."')]]");
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[`xs:dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) data type is not part of XPath 1.0 data model and the algorithm for time zone conversion is complex (Suppose that you must to do it in standard SQL!).

**My advice**: upgrade to XPath 2.0 engine

As proof of concept, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="
        /SomeData/MyData/Date[
           xs:dateTime(.) >= xs:dateTime('2011-10-01T00:00:00-05:00')
              and
           xs:dateTime('2011-10-02T00:00:00-05:00') > xs:dateTime(.)
        ]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this well formed input:

```
<SomeData>
    <MyData uID="123456">
        <MyInfo A="1" B="2" C="3"/>
        <Date>2011-10-02T00:30:00</Date>
    </MyData>
    <MyData uID="123456">
        <MyInfo A="1" B="2" C="3"/>
        <Date>2011-10-01T00:30:00</Date>
    </MyData>
</SomeData>
```

Output:

```
<Date>2011-10-02T00:30:00</Date>
```